# Stack trace of javax.transaction.RollbackException missing the cause

Tags: java, exception, junit

I have a stack trace with a `javax.transaction.RollbackException`:

> [...] Caused by:
>   ch.ethz.id.wai.lakshmi.engine.common.LakshmiException: Error
>   processing user transaction. at
>   ch.ethz.id.wai.lakshmi.engine.common.TransactionHelper.commitTransaction(TransactionHelper.java:79)
>   at
>   ch.ethz.id.wai.lakshmi.stdcmp.persistency.StandardPersistency.registerOrder(StandardPersistency.java:110)
>   Caused by: javax.transaction.RollbackException: Transaction marked for
>   rollback. at
>   com.sun.enterprise.transaction.JavaEETransactionImpl.commit(JavaEETransactionImpl.java:473)
>   at
>   com.sun.enterprise.transaction.JavaEETransactionManagerSimplified.commit(JavaEETransactionManagerSimplified.java:855)
>   at
>   com.sun.enterprise.transaction.UserTransactionImpl.commit(UserTransactionImpl.java:208)
>   at
>   ch.ethz.id.wai.lakshmi.engine.common.TransactionHelper.commitTransaction(TransactionHelper.java:74)
>
> at
>   org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1387)
>   at
>   org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1310)
>   at
>   org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1316)
>   at
>   org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl$CallbackExceptionMapperImpl.mapManagedFlushFailure(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1510)
>   at
>   org.hibernate.engine.transaction.synchronization.internal.SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletion(SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorImpl.java:109)
>   at
>   org.hibernate.engine.transaction.synchronization.internal.RegisteredSynchronization.beforeCompletion(RegisteredSynchronization.java:53)
>   at
>   com.sun.enterprise.transaction.JavaEETransactionImpl.commit(JavaEETransactionImpl.java:435)
>
> at
>   org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:54)
>   at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125)
>   at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110)
>   at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractStatementProxyHandler.continueInvocation(AbstractStatementProxyHandler.java:129)
>   at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractProxyHandler.invoke(AbstractProxyHandler.java:81)
>   at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy233.executeUpdate(Unknown Source) at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:56)
>   at
>   org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3028)
>   at
>   org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3469)
>   at
>   org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:88)
>   at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:362)
>   at
>   org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:354)
>   at
>   org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:275)
>   at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:326)
>   at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:52)
>   at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1213) at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:402)
>   at
>   org.hibernate.engine.transaction.synchronization.internal.SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletion(SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorImpl.java:104)
>
> at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:439) at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:395) at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:802) at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:436) at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:186) at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:521) at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:205)
>   at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForRows(T4CPreparedStatement.java:1008)
>   at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1307)
>   at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3449)
>   at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3530)
>   at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1350)
>   at
>   com.sun.gjc.spi.base.PreparedStatementWrapper.executeUpdate(PreparedStatementWrapper.java:125)
>   at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractStatementProxyHandler.continueInvocation(AbstractStatementProxyHandler.java:122)

The `RollbackException` has a cause that I can see while debugging:

> javax.persistence.PersistenceException:
>   org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: ORA-22295: cannot bind
>   more than 4000 bytes data to LOB and LONG columns in 1 statement

which is in turn caused by

> org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: ORA-22295: cannot bind
>   more than 4000 bytes data to LOB and LONG columns in 1 statement

But the cause of the `RollbackExeption` is not shown in the stack trace (which would ease the debugging of the errors).

Any idea of the reason?

**Edit**

I added a try-catch in the test method (JUnit):

```
@Test
public void foo() throws Throwable {
    try {
        // test code generating the exception
} catch ( Exception e ) {
    // here the exception cause is still there
}
```

Since this method is called directly by JUnit the exception is still OK when it leaves my code.

[image]

Comment: Is there a try catch this happens in you can show us?

Comment: @CorayThan No after the exception is thrown it it propagated to junit and shown on the console. At the last spot in my code the cause is there. After that if I step in the debugger I'm no more in code that I wrote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was Ant erroneously filtering part of the exception trace

From the [Junit task documentation](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/junit.html):

> filtertrace   Filter out Junit and Ant stack frames from error and failure stack traces.

It defaults to `on` but it does not only filter Junit and Ant frames: setting it to off the cause of the rollback is shown.

Answer (score 0):

If you like to have the cause shown in the exception, I guess your only chance is to open a bug/improvement request at `Glassfish`. I looked at the source code of [JavaEETransactionImpl](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.glassfish.transaction/jta/3.1.1/com/sun/enterprise/transaction/JavaEETransactionImpl.java/), which is where the `RollbackException` is thrown and at line 473 the code is:

```
rbe = new RollbackException(sm.getString("enterprise_distributedtx.mark_rollback"));
```

As you can see, I am checking version `3.1.1`, so in case you have a different version please take a look to the right source code (which I doubt will differ anyway).

Comment: But the RollbackException has the `cause` set (it is visible with a debugger): see screenshot.

Comment: What happens if you re-throw the exception after you catch it? does the cause disappear? I mean: `@Test
public void foo() throws Throwable {
    try {
        /* test code generating the exception */
} catch ( Exception e ) {
    /* here the exception cause is still there */
throw e;
}`

Comment: no changes. If I create a new exception (`throw new Exception(e)`) I see the additional cause in the stack trace but the cause of the `RollbackException` is still not there.